# Convertion of Timestamp variable in Postgre's request

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

Tried to do Postgre's request with java.sql.Timestamp variables, but met such error:

`bad SQL grammar [select extract(year from LOCALTIMESTAMP) -extract(year from ?)]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function pg_catalog.date_part(unknown, unknown) is not unique`

I don't understand, why PostgreSql doesn't recognized Timestamp variable.
Code:

```
private void myFN(Timestamp dt) {
        rowSet = jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet("select extract(year from LOCALTIMESTAMP) -extract(year from ?)", dt);
        rowSet = jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet("select extract(year from LOCALTIMESTAMP) -extract(year from ?)",
                new Object[] { dt }, new int[] { Types.TIMESTAMP });
    }
```

P.S. SQL doesn't recognize variable in both requests.

Comment: Try this, an explicit CAST(): extract(year from CAST(? AS DATE))

Comment: Are you trying to query for time stamps that occurred in the last 216 months?

Comment: What is the *exact* data type of your time stamp column?

Comment: FYI, the modern *java.time* classes entirely replaced the functionality of the terrible legacy date-time classes. So no need to mix them. Seeing `Date` and `LocalDateTime` in the same line makes me cringe.

Comment: I tried explicit CAST to date and it worked. But i want to know why SQL doesn't recognized Timestamp variable.
Given code is just an example of code that generates such error(```dt``` can be any Timestamp date).
There is no column in code, i just put ```java.sql.Timestamp``` variable into request

Comment: @BasilBourque What do u mean by time stamp column?

Comment: The column in your database table in which you are storing timestamps? The column against which you are making a query?

Comment: @BasilBourque Timestamp